# Puzzling grammar in a Sappho line

Tags: greek, sappho, greek-to-english-translation

A combination of LP fragments, found at 6.A.i [here](https://michelegorini.blogspot.com/2019/05/the-rest-of-sappho.html), has the following first two lines:

> ἐπτάξατε̣ [          ] δροσ[ό]εσσα[-     ]
>   δάφνας ὄτα̣ [          ] . αι

The [Italian anthology](https://www.openstarts.units.it/bitstream/10077/11675/1/Saffo_frammenti_2015.pdf) I first found this in supplements:

> ἐπτάξατε̣ [μέν, παῖδες, ὐπ' ἔρνη] δροσ[ό]εσσα[ν ἄγνας]
>   δάφνας ὄτα̣ [          ] . αι

translating:

> You cowered, [oh children, under the] dewy [branches] of a [holy]
>   Laurel when …

Now, "dewy branches" doesn't seem to work grammatically, because ἔρνη<ἔρνος is neuter plural while δροσόεσσαν<δροσόεις is feminine singular. The feminine dewy is from a papyrus, so we can't change it to neuter plural δροσόεντα. I believe we can't put "dewy" with the laurel, because doing so would give δροσοέσσᾱς, where the long alpha is inmetrical. So how does this translation match the original? And how does the grammar of that original work?